# Getting “field has incomplete type” and "conflicting types"

Tags: c, ubuntu, ffmpeg, pjsip

I'm trying build pjsip from source with video support by gcc on ubuntu. After i success full run ./configure and make dep, i run make and i have error below:

```
../src/pjmedia/ffmpeg_util.c:46:18: error: field ‘codec_id’ has incomplete type
../src/pjmedia/ffmpeg_util.c:148:13: error: conflicting types for ‘pjmedia_format_id_to_CodecID’
../src/pjmedia/ffmpeg_util.h:23:13: note: previous declaration of ‘pjmedia_format_id_to_CodecID’ was here
../src/pjmedia/ffmpeg_util.c: In function ‘pjmedia_format_id_to_CodecID’:
../src/pjmedia/ffmpeg_util.c:154:35: warning: comparison between pointer and integer [enabled by default]
../src/pjmedia/ffmpeg_util.c:155:6: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
../src/pjmedia/ffmpeg_util.c:155:6: warning: statement with no effect [-Wunused-value]
../src/pjmedia/ffmpeg_util.c:160:5: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
../src/pjmedia/ffmpeg_util.c:160:5: warning: statement with no effect [-Wunused-value]
../src/pjmedia/ffmpeg_util.c: At top level:
../src/pjmedia/ffmpeg_util.c:164:55: error: parameter 1 (‘codec_id’) has incomplete type
```

Here is the code in ffmpeg_util.h and ffmpeg_util.c

ffmpeg_util.h

```
#ifndef __PJMEDIA_FFMPEG_UTIL_H__
#define __PJMEDIA_FFMPEG_UTIL_H__

#include <pjmedia/format.h>

#ifdef _MSC_VER
#   ifndef __cplusplus
#   define inline _inline
#   endif
#   pragma warning(disable:4244) /* possible loss of data */
#endif

#include <libavutil/avutil.h>
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>

void pjmedia_ffmpeg_add_ref();
void pjmedia_ffmpeg_dec_ref();

pj_status_t pjmedia_format_id_to_PixelFormat(pjmedia_format_id fmt_id,
                         enum PixelFormat *pixel_format);

pj_status_t PixelFormat_to_pjmedia_format_id(enum PixelFormat pf,
                         pjmedia_format_id *fmt_id);

pj_status_t pjmedia_format_id_to_CodecID(pjmedia_format_id fmt_id,
                     enum CodecID *codec_id);

pj_status_t CodecID_to_pjmedia_format_id(enum CodecID codec_id,
                     pjmedia_format_id *fmt_id);

#endif /* __PJMEDIA_FFMPEG_UTIL_H__ */
```

ffmpeg_util.c

```
#include <pjmedia/types.h>
#include <pj/errno.h>
#include <pj/log.h>
#include <pj/string.h>

#if PJMEDIA_HAS_LIBAVFORMAT && PJMEDIA_HAS_LIBAVUTIL

#include "ffmpeg_util.h"
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>

#define MAKE_VER(mj,mn,mi)  ((mj << 16) | (mn << 8) | (mi << 0))
#define VER_AT_LEAST(mj,mn,mi)  (MAKE_VER(LIBAVUTIL_VERSION_MAJOR, \
                                          LIBAVUTIL_VERSION_MINOR, \
                                          LIBAVUTIL_VERSION_MICRO) >= \
                                 MAKE_VER(mj,mn,mi))



/* Conversion table between pjmedia_format_id and PixelFormat */
static const struct ffmpeg_fmt_table_t
{
    pjmedia_format_id   id;
    enum PixelFormat    pf;
} ffmpeg_fmt_table[] =
{
    { PJMEDIA_FORMAT_RGBA, PIX_FMT_RGBA},
    { PJMEDIA_FORMAT_RGB24,PIX_FMT_BGR24},
    { PJMEDIA_FORMAT_BGRA, PIX_FMT_BGRA},
#if VER_AT_LEAST(51,20,1)
    { PJMEDIA_FORMAT_GBRP, PIX_FMT_GBR24P},
#endif

    { PJMEDIA_FORMAT_AYUV, PIX_FMT_NONE},
    { PJMEDIA_FORMAT_YUY2, PIX_FMT_YUYV422},
    { PJMEDIA_FORMAT_UYVY, PIX_FMT_UYVY422},
    { PJMEDIA_FORMAT_I420, PIX_FMT_YUV420P},
    //{ PJMEDIA_FORMAT_YV12, PIX_FMT_YUV420P},
    { PJMEDIA_FORMAT_I422, PIX_FMT_YUV422P},
    { PJMEDIA_FORMAT_I420JPEG, PIX_FMT_YUVJ420P},
    { PJMEDIA_FORMAT_I422JPEG, PIX_FMT_YUVJ422P},
};

/* Conversion table between pjmedia_format_id and CodecID */
static const struct ffmpeg_codec_table_t
{
    pjmedia_format_id   id;
    enum CodecID    codec_id;
} ffmpeg_codec_table[] =
{
    {PJMEDIA_FORMAT_H261,   CODEC_ID_H261},
    {PJMEDIA_FORMAT_H263,   CODEC_ID_H263},
    {PJMEDIA_FORMAT_H263P,  CODEC_ID_H263P},
    {PJMEDIA_FORMAT_H264,   CODEC_ID_H264},
    {PJMEDIA_FORMAT_MPEG1VIDEO, CODEC_ID_MPEG1VIDEO},
    {PJMEDIA_FORMAT_MPEG2VIDEO, CODEC_ID_MPEG2VIDEO},
    {PJMEDIA_FORMAT_MPEG4,  CODEC_ID_MPEG4},
    {PJMEDIA_FORMAT_MJPEG,  CODEC_ID_MJPEG}
};

static int pjmedia_ffmpeg_ref_cnt;

static void ffmpeg_log_cb(void* ptr, int level, const char* fmt, va_list vl);

void pjmedia_ffmpeg_add_ref()
{
    if (pjmedia_ffmpeg_ref_cnt++ == 0) {
    av_log_set_level(AV_LOG_ERROR);
    av_log_set_callback(&ffmpeg_log_cb);
    av_register_all();
    }
}

void pjmedia_ffmpeg_dec_ref()
{
    if (pjmedia_ffmpeg_ref_cnt-- == 1) {
    /* How to shutdown ffmpeg? */
    }

    if (pjmedia_ffmpeg_ref_cnt < 0) pjmedia_ffmpeg_ref_cnt = 0;
}


static void ffmpeg_log_cb(void* ptr, int level, const char* fmt, va_list vl)
{
    const char *LOG_SENDER = "ffmpeg";
    enum { LOG_LEVEL = 5 };
    char buf[100];
    int bufsize = sizeof(buf), len;
    pj_str_t fmt_st;

    /* Custom callback needs to filter log level by itself */
    if (level > av_log_get_level())
    return;

    /* Add original ffmpeg sender to log format */
    if (ptr) {
    AVClass* avc = *(AVClass**)ptr;
    len = pj_ansi_snprintf(buf, bufsize, "%s: ", avc->item_name(ptr));
    bufsize -= len;
    }

    /* Copy original log format */
    len = pj_ansi_strlen(fmt);
    if (len > bufsize-1)
    len = bufsize-1;
    pj_memcpy(buf+sizeof(buf)-bufsize, fmt, len);
    bufsize -= len;

    /* Trim log format */
    pj_strset(&fmt_st, buf, sizeof(buf)-bufsize);
    pj_strrtrim(&fmt_st);
    buf[fmt_st.slen] = '\0';

    pj_log(LOG_SENDER, LOG_LEVEL, buf, vl);
}


pj_status_t pjmedia_format_id_to_PixelFormat(pjmedia_format_id fmt_id,
                         enum PixelFormat *pixel_format)
{
    unsigned i;
    for (i=0; i<PJ_ARRAY_SIZE(ffmpeg_fmt_table); ++i) {
    const struct ffmpeg_fmt_table_t *t = &ffmpeg_fmt_table[i];
    if (t->id==fmt_id && t->pf != PIX_FMT_NONE) {
        *pixel_format = t->pf;
        return PJ_SUCCESS;
    }
    }

    *pixel_format = PIX_FMT_NONE;
    return PJ_ENOTFOUND;
}

pj_status_t PixelFormat_to_pjmedia_format_id(enum PixelFormat pf,
                         pjmedia_format_id *fmt_id)
{
    unsigned i;
    for (i=0; i<PJ_ARRAY_SIZE(ffmpeg_fmt_table); ++i) {
    const struct ffmpeg_fmt_table_t *t = &ffmpeg_fmt_table[i];
    if (t->pf == pf) {
        if (fmt_id) *fmt_id = t->id;
        return PJ_SUCCESS;
    }
    }

    return PJ_ENOTFOUND;
}

pj_status_t pjmedia_format_id_to_CodecID(pjmedia_format_id fmt_id,
                     enum CodecID *codec_id)
{
    unsigned i;
    for (i=0; i<PJ_ARRAY_SIZE(ffmpeg_codec_table); ++i) {
    const struct ffmpeg_codec_table_t *t = &ffmpeg_codec_table[i];
    if (t->id==fmt_id && t->codec_id != PIX_FMT_NONE) {
        *codec_id = t->codec_id;
        return PJ_SUCCESS;
    }
    }

    *codec_id = PIX_FMT_NONE;
    return PJ_ENOTFOUND;
}

pj_status_t CodecID_to_pjmedia_format_id(enum CodecID codec_id,
                     pjmedia_format_id *fmt_id)
{
    unsigned i;
    for (i=0; i<PJ_ARRAY_SIZE(ffmpeg_codec_table); ++i) {
    const struct ffmpeg_codec_table_t *t = &ffmpeg_codec_table[i];
    if (t->codec_id == codec_id) {
        if (fmt_id) *fmt_id = t->id;
        return PJ_SUCCESS;
    }
    }

    return PJ_ENOTFOUND;
}


#ifdef _MSC_VER
#   pragma comment( lib, "avformat.lib")
#   pragma comment( lib, "avutil.lib")
#endif

#endif  /* #if PJMEDIA_HAS_LIBAVFORMAT && PJMEDIA_HAS_LIBAVUTIL */
```

Help me fix this error!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like most of errors you are seeing are rooted in the fact `enum CodecID` is not found. Not sure where it might be in your source, but [this commit](http://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-cvslog/2012-August/053381.html) discusses renaming it to `AVCodecID`. Are you sure you have an up-to-date source?

Comment: Thanks! I success full build after rename it